# Gridview not refreshing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So I have a gridview of a list of employees. An user can select an employee and do various tasks with the employee, including deleting an employee in this list. I try to update the gridview after an user is done selecting that employee. It just comes up blank. I would like it to come up with the updated list of employees. This is odd because when the page loads the gridview is correct.

I have include my Page_Load and one of the methods that sends the user back to the gridview.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (EmployeeWrapper.GetSessionWrapper() == null)
        {
            ddlArea.Visible = true;
            lblArea.Text = ddlArea.Text;
        }
        else lblArea.Text = EmployeeWrapper.GetSessionWrapper().Name;
        string test = "SELECT [EmployeeName], [BeginTime], [Task_Name] FROM [ActiveTaskView]  WHERE ([Area] = '" + lblArea.Text + "')";
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = test;
    }


    protected void cmdCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblName.Enabled = false;
        lblName.Text = "";
        lblNewTask.Visible = false;
        lblSta.Visible = false;
        ddlNewTask.Visible = false;
        txtStartTime.Visible = false;
        cmdStart.Visible = false;
        cmdCancel.Visible = false;
        string test = "SELECT [EmployeeName], [BeginTime], [Task_Name] FROM [ActiveTaskView]  WHERE ([Area] = '" + ddlArea.Text + "')";
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = test;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After whatever operations you want to do. call `gridView.DataBind();`